# ¿Cómo pasar de decimal a binario en Java?

Tags: java, array, algoritmos, matemáticas

Estoy haciendo un programa con arrays que convierte un número binario a un decimal y después que vuelva a ser binario,  tratando cada una de las posiciones del número binario, mirando si es 0 o 1 y realizando la operación correspondiente en base a dicha posición. De binario a decimal lo conseguí, aunque salen ceros de mas creo que esta bien, y ahora para pasar de decimal a binario me he atascado, la manera de resolverlo es dividiendo el numero que se ponga para pasar a binario entre 2 y el cociente otra vez entre 2, así hasta que el cociente sea menor que 2, y el número binario son los residuos de esas operaciones, dejo lo que hice a ver si alguien me puede ayudar.

```
public class CalculadoraBinaria {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        //De binario a decimal

        double[] binario = {1000};
        int exp = 0;
        double decimal = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < binario.length; i++) {
            for(exp = 0; exp < 4; exp++) {
                decimal = binario[i] * (int)Math.pow(2, exp);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("El número binario 1000 en decimal es: " + decimal);

        //De decimal a binario

        double[] decimal2 = {8000};
        double binario2 = 0;
        for(int n = 0; n < decimal2.length; n++) {
            binario2 = decimal2[n] % 2;
        }
        System.out.println(binario2);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Digamos que tenemos el siguiente número decimal: 13. Para pasar de decimal a binario tenemos que dividir todos los cocientes entre dos y luego coger los restos al revés, junto con el último cociente, de derecha a izquierda.

Haciendo la división:

```
13|2
  └───
1  6 |2
     └───
   0  3 |2
        └───
      1  1
```

Por lo que el 13<sub>(10)</sub> es igual que 1101<sub>(2)</sub>

Dicho esto, vamos analizar como podemos hacerlo. Deberemos de coger todos los restos más el último cociente. A su vez, tendremos que almacenar el cociente anterior para poder sacar a su vez de nuevo el resto. Iremos almacenando los restos en un `ArrayList<String>` para poder insertar los elementos al principio del String. Posteriormente lo convertiremos a String para imprimirlo.

Con código, en este caso, voy a englobarlo en una función para que pueda ser más modular en un futuro:

```
public static String obtenerBinario(int numero){
   ArrayList<String> binario = new ArrayList<String>();
   int resto;
   String binarioString = "";

   do{
      resto = numero%2;
      numero = numero/2;
      binario.add(0, Integer.toString(resto));
   }while(numero > 2); //Haremos el bucle hasta que el cociente no se pueda dividir mas

   binario.add(0, Integer.toString(numero)); //Cogeremos el ultimo cociente

   //Cogemos cada uno de los elementos del ArrayList y los juntamos en un String
   for(int i = 0; i < binario.size(); i++){
       binarioString += binario.get(i);
   }
   return binarioString;
 }
```

De esta manera, si tienes un array, puedes ir iterando por cada uno de los elementos del array sacando su binario. Por ejemplo, para los siguientes números:

```
int[] array = {13, 150, 20, 5};

for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
   System.out.println(obtenerBinario(array[i]));
}
```

Obtendríamos la siguiente salida:

```
1101
10010110
10100
101
```

Comment: Al final lo haré así, ya que con arrays se me complica bastante con el decimal...: int decimal2 = 8;
  String binario2 = "";
  while ( decimal2 > 0 ) {
   binario2 = decimal2 % 2 + binario2;
   decimal2 = decimal2 /2;
   }

Answer (score 8):

> ¿Cómo pasar de decimal a binario en Java?

No me rompo la cabeza con algoritmos si no necesito hacerlo. Simplemente uso lo que ya está disponible en la librería estándar.

- Decimal --> Binario: [`Integer.toBinaryString(decimal)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString-int-)
- Binario --> Decimal: [`Integer.parseInt(binario, 2)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-int-) (o, si tienes Java 8, puedes usar [`Integer.parseUnsignedInt(binario, 2)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseUnsignedInt-java.lang.String-int-))

**Código:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int decimalInicial = 8;

    // de decimal a binario
    String binario = Integer.toBinaryString(decimalInicial);
    System.out.println(binario); // 1000

    // de binario a decimal
    int decimalConvertido = Integer.parseInt(binario, 2);
    System.out.println(decimalConvertido); // 8
}
```

**Resultado:**

> 1000
>   8

Answer (score 1):

Pues para convertir de decimal a binario se te va a complicar sí lo quieres hacer tomando el número como un array, sería más fácil sí tomas todo el número, pues como tu lo mencionaste:

> la manera de resolverlo es dividiendo el numero que se ponga para
>   pasar a binario entre 2 y el cociente otra vez entre 2, así hasta que
>   el cociente sea menor que 2
>   Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de como sería el código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int numero, exp, digito;
        double binario;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        do{  
            System.out.print("Introduce un numero entero >= 0: ");
            numero = sc.nextInt();
        }while(numero<0);

        exp=0;
        binario=0;
        while(numero!=0){
                digito = numero % 2;            
                binario = binario + digito * Math.pow(10, exp);   
                exp++;
                numero = numero/2;
        }
        System.out.printf("Binario: %.0f %n", binario);
    }
```

Espero te sirva para lo que estás buscando.

Answer (score 0):

> Este pedazo de código hace la conversion de números positivos a binario

```
 int numero = 24; //Declaramos el número decimal que deseamos pasar a binario. 
    String binario = ""; //Variable aux para guardar la cadena de binarios.
    while (numero > 0) { 
 //Utilización de if simplificado en el cual se verifica si el residuo de la división es 0 en caso de cumplirse se agrega 0 a la var aux.
        binario = numero % 2 == 0 ? "0" + binario : "1" + binario;
        numero = numero / 2; //Esta condición es la permite salir del bucle.
    }
    System.err.print(binario+"\n"); //Imprimes el resultado almacenado en la variable "binario"
}
```

> Resultado: 11000

Comment: Deberias explicar que hace tu codigo y como funciona. Echale un vistazo a [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Con esto es suficiente:

```
public static void main(String []args) {
    int numero=25;
    String base2="";
    while(numero>0) {
        base2=(numero%2)+base2;
        numero/=2;  
    }
    System.out.println(base2);
}
```

Comment: Intenta explicar que hace el código para realizar una buena respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Hola espero que les sirva:
Para convertir cualquier numero decimal a binario en java:
Copia el codigo y ejecutalo:

```
package Ejercicios;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class prueba {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    String bin = ""; //Acumulamos en un String los restos de la division
    int numero; //numero que queremos convertir a binario

    System.out.print("Ingrese un numero: ");
    numero = entrada.nextInt();

    while (numero > 0) {
        if (numero % 2 == 0) {
            bin = "0" + bin;
            /*ponemos el +bin despues del cero para que en nuestra cadena(String bin) 
        primero se muestre el "0" y luego el valor anterior de nuestra cadena
        Si lo hacemos al reves, osea bin=bin+"0" nos saldria el valor binario pero al reves
             */
        } else {
            bin = "1" + bin;
        }
        numero = numero / 2;//vamos disminuyendo el numero a la mitad ya que en binario tenemos que dividir entre 2
    }
    System.out.println(bin);
}
}
```