# Java como pasar un binario tipo int a la traducción y en tipo String

Tags: java

como puedo pasar un int que contiene un binario, y este lo quiero convertir al equivalente en tipo String

es decir

```
   int binario = 1001000;
//Pasarlo a String  con este valor letra="O";
```

Comment: Creo que lo apropiado sería usar una variable tipo Byte[] para este tipo de tareas, ¿Por qué usarías un int?

Comment: un int **siempre** contiene un número en binario, el de tu ejemplo contiene el 1001000 (valor en decimal), que es lo mismo que `11110100011000101000b`

Comment: Son los requisitos que me ponen, se que es muy innesesario

Comment: Como podria pasar de decimal a binario, hay algun modulo hecho ya o viceversa? y tal vez por eso me han exigido int

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cómo pasar de decimal a binario en Java?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/32796/c%c3%b3mo-pasar-de-decimal-a-binario-en-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se puede asignar un numero binario a byte, short, int ,long... Solo hay que poner "0b" al principio del numero para que el compilador lo lea como un numero binario.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int binario = 0b1001000;//72 en decimal
    char letra = (char) binario;//se puede convertir a una letra equivalente al valor del numero en la tabla ascii
    String ascii = String.valueOf(letra);//se puede convertir char a String
    String numberoBinario = Integer.toBinaryString(binario); //convierte un int a una String con su valor binario

    System.out.println("Valor en decimal = " + binario);
    System.out.println("Valor en binario = " + numberoBinario);
    System.out.println("Valor ASCII = " + letra);
}
```

En la [documentación de java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/binary-literals.html) se explica como asignar numeros que no sean decimales.

Comment: Gracias, ahora una pregunta con 0b, como puedo introducirlo, si estoy montando el binario digito a digito. no sé como insertar 0b en su valor

Comment: Si te refieres a pasar de una String con un valor binario a int puedes usar esto.                                                                                       String valorBinario ="1001000";
        int valorDecimal = Integer.parseInt(valorBinario, 2);

Comment: Me refiero a montar el binario digito a digito sobre un int, no sé como introducir el 0b para que me lo coja luego en el String

Comment: Pues no se exactamente a que te refieres. Prueba a crear otra pregunta te podran ayudar mejor.